# Approaches to online tutoring

Tags: startups

At present the prevailing mode of online tutoring seems to involve websites that connect tutors directly with prospective students.

A slightly different approach might instead allow tutors to connect with students by way of the (appropriately anonymized) schools attended by the students or that the tutors are remotely affiliated with. This approach seems like it would be moderately safer, exposing prospective students and tutors to fewer risks vis a vis academic integrity, and would allow tutors to engage more profitably with teachers as external consultants or content creation contractors as well as helping students stay up to speed with their classmates or peers elsewhere.

It seems like it must have been tried at least once before, however, and I'm worried that I haven't come across anything like it over the last two or so years while I have been exploring the somewhat turbid waters of online tutoring.

Are there obvious or not so obvious shortcomings or obstacles to this idea that I'm missing, or could it be worth exploring?

Answer (score 1):

The primary detractor, as I see it, is that it opens schools up to direct liability.

Should someone nefarious pass themselves off as a tutor, and a school directly connects students with that "tutor", the school *may* be held liable for negligence.

To this end, undue stress in terms of work hours and costs would be placed upon schools to ensure they vet all prospective tutors accordingly.

That, to me, is too much burden to place on an already stressed educational system (in the US).

Comment: OK.  What I'm hearing is that the primary concern is one that is basically unavoidable in the course of collective enterprise or any sort of interaction between human beings.  (Ironically, it sounds vastly less sketchy than the current mode of tutoring, which offers very little if any guidance to tutors w.r.t accountability and academic integrity on a systemic level.)  Which is more negligent: being open to hiring third party tutors to help students who are struggling, or digging your head into the sand and pretending that tutors don't exist?